# String file path of image from media Store is not always the same

Tags: java, uri

I trying to create a custom photo gallery which the user can store Images from MediaStore photo gallery,
And my target is that the user can only the store different Image in database, if it is a duplicate Image it will not store .So , Im thinking hey, I can use the filepath as sort of A Id to check for duplicate Images. But evertime I restart the app and repick the same picture the Uri/filepath is not the same espicially the lastpart of the filePath/Uri

My Weird Implementation to Check duplicate:

```
public void checkAndSetPhotoGalleryData() throws IOException {
       RoomDB db = RoomDB.getInstance(this);
       PhotoGalleryData photoGalleryData = new PhotoGalleryData();
       String stringUri = String.valueOf(imageUri);
       String lastPartFile = stringUri.substring(stringUri.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
       TextView testThis = findViewById(R.id.testName);
      testThis.setText(db_path);
       if(photoGarList.isEmpty()) {
           try {
               InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
               byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);
               photoGalleryData.setKey_Value_Quiz(String.valueOf(lastPartFile));
               photoGalleryData.setPhoto(inputData);
               db.questionDao().insert(photoGalleryData);
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }if(!photoGarList.isEmpty())
       {for(int i = 0; i<photoGarList.size();i++){
           if (photoGarList.get(i).getKey_Value_Quiz().length() > 0 && !photoGarList.isEmpty() && photoGarList.get(i).getKey_Value_Quiz().equals(String.valueOf(lastPartFile))) {
               showLongToast("Are Identical");

           }
           if (photoGarList.get(i).getKey_Value_Quiz().length() > 0 && !photoGarList.isEmpty() && !photoGarList.get(i).getKey_Value_Quiz().equals(String.valueOf(lastPartFile)) && i == photoGarList.size()-1) {
               try {
                   InputStream iStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                   byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);
                   photoGalleryData.setKey_Value_Quiz(String.valueOf(lastPartFile));
                   photoGalleryData.setPhoto(inputData);
                   db.questionDao().insert(photoGalleryData);
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }
       }

   }
```

lastPart of filePath:

```
///both of this are the same picture:
KeyValue:924270434
KeyValue:239256090
```

I guess that for security reason they change the last part every time, So I want to know is there any constant factor of a picture except for byte[] or Bitmap(Size is to Huge to store at once and this is not the case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You could use simple pixel by pixel comparison of the images.**

Try to use ImageMagic:
[ImageMagic](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/#difference)

Or you could try Java OpenCV: [How to compare two images using Java OpenCV library](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-compare-two-images-using-java-opencv-library)